# Enviar dados para uma ActionResult de um Controller diferente do atual

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Como fazer um `post` enviando dados para um `ActionResult` de um `Controller` diferente do atual ? Exemplo:

Tenho um link chamado `lnkEnviarDados` e preciso fazer um post na página enviando o conteúdo das variáveis quando clico nesse link.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Pessoa", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="grid">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="lnkEnviarDados" name="downloaditem" id="downloaditem2" data-id_Atributo_1="6" data-id_Atributo_2="1" data-id_Atributo_3="2" target="_blank">
                        <span class="idSpan">Regular</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tody>
    </table>
}

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {         
        $(document).on('click', '.lnkEnviarDados', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var _Atributo_1 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_1");
            var _Atributo_2 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_2");
            var _Atributo_3 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_3");

            //Fazer um post deste controller para enviar os dados acima
            //para um outro Controller chamado "BaixarConta"

        });
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER BaixarConta**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BaixarConta(int _Atributo_3, int _Atributo_2, int _Atributo_3)
{

}
```

Comment: O seu ActionResult tem o mesmo nome do seu controler?

Comment: @Tiago S não tem o mesmo nome, mas vi na sua resposta como proceder, vou implementar e em seguida postarei aqui o resultado. Obrigado!.

Comment: @Tiago S o envio dos dados funciona perfeitamente, porém a `ActionResult` retorna um `FileStreamResult` que não funciona exemplo: return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf"); o fato de fazer o post da página desse jeito influencia o não funcionamento do return ?

Comment: Sim, totalmente, mas isso foge do escopo da sua pergunta. Marca a resposta como aceita e se possivel um up vote :)  e crie uma nova pergunta, por exemplo de como fazer download de arquivo via $.ajax()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só utilizar o @Url.Action()

O primeiro parâmentro é a `action` e o segundo o `controler`, ou seja,

> @Url.Action("NOME DA ACTION","NOME DO CONTROLLER")

Utilizando o $.ajax() ficaria assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {         
        $(document).on('click', '.lnkEnviarDados', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var _Atributo_1 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_1");
            var _Atributo_2 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_2");
            var _Atributo_3 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_3");

            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("BaixarConta","BaixarConta"),
                method:'post',
                data:{_Atributo_1:_Atributo_1 ,_Atributo_2:_Atributo_2,_Atributo_3:_Atributo_3}
                success:function(retorno){
                      //TODO:Implemente as suas funções para atualizar a tela.
                });


        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o @Url.Action onde

```
 @Url.Action("NomeDaView", "NomeDoController", new {Attributo1 = valor, atributo2 = valor2, atributo3 = valor3}
```

Vi que vc criou dentro de um form, pode enviar todo o form com seus dados atraves do submit também, basta a Action usar o FormCollection ficando assim

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BaixarConta(FormCollection Form)
{
var teste = Form["Attr1"];

return RedirectToAction("Index") para retorna para a main page
}
```