# Como fazer download de arquivo via $.ajax()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, stream-de-arquivos

Essa dúvida surgiu a partir desse post [Enviar dados para uma ActionResult de um Controller diferente do atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212026/enviar-dados-para-uma-actionresult-de-um-controller-diferente-do-atual?noredirect=1#comment433544_212026) respondido pelo [Tiago S](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/44289/tiago-s), atualmente tenho essa `ActionResult` que faz download de arquivo através de um Post em uma View e preciso fazer através do $.ajax():

```
 $(document).ready(function () {         
        $(document).on('click', '.lnkEnviarDados', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var _Atributo_1 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_1");
            var _Atributo_2 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_2");
            var _Atributo_3 = $(this).attr("data-Atributo_3");

            $.ajax({
                url:'@Url.Action("BaixarConta","BaixarConta"),
                method:'post',
                data:{_Atributo_1:_Atributo_1 ,_Atributo_2:_Atributo_2,_Atributo_3:_Atributo_3}
                success:function(retorno){

                });


        });
    }
```

O problema é que o download não é executado e acredito pelo fato da chamada ser feita por JQuery.

Abaixo é a ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BaixarConta(int _Atributo_1, int _Atributo_2, int _Atributo_3)
{
     //faço o processamento do arquivo a ser baixado
     var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                         .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1.5)
                                         .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                         .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                         .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                         .SetIntelligentShrinking(true).SetCreateInternalLinks(true)
                                         .SetAllowLocalContent(true), _ObterSelecionado.DocumentoHtml.ToString());

                file = new MemoryStream();
                file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
                byte[] arquivo = pdf;
                MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
                pdfStream.Write(arquivo.ToArray(), 0, arquivo.ToArray().Length);
                pdfStream.Position = 0;
     return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

> Aqui implementei a sugestão do [Tiago S](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/44289/tiago-s)

```
  [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Download(string file)
            {             
                 string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                 var pdfStream = TempData[file]; 
                return  File((byte[])pdfStream, "application/pdf"); //fazendo uma lteração aqui nessa linha pois estava dando erro de conversão
            }
```

> O **problema** é que sempre retorna `null` no parâmetro `string file`.

Na **View** adicionei apenas `new { target="_blank"}` para abrir em uma nova aba do navegador.

Na **Controller** adaptei

```
#region :: Converte o atributo DocumentoHTML em tipo PDF ::
                    var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                             .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1.5)
                                             .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                             .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                             .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                             .SetIntelligentShrinking(true).SetCreateInternalLinks(true)
                                             .SetAllowLocalContent(true), _ObterSelecionado.DocumentoHtml.ToString());

                    file = new MemoryStream();
                    file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
                    byte[] arquivo = pdf;
                    MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
                    pdfStream.Write(arquivo.ToArray(), 0, arquivo.ToArray().Length);
                    pdfStream.Position = 0;

                    ///Aqui alterei conforme sugestão do Tiago S
                    string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    TempData[handle] = pdfStream;
                    return Json(new { FileGuid = handle });

                    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução seria você gerar um link de download temporário e fazer uma requisição GET

Ao invés de retornar um FileStreamResult, você retorna um Json com uma chave

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BaixarConta(int _Atributo_1, int _Atributo_2, int _Atributo_3)
{
     //faço o processamento do arquivo a ser baixado
     string handle=Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     TempData[handle]=pdfStream;

     return Json( new { FileGuid = handle});
}
```

Esta chave você utiliza no ajax para gerar o link

No seu Ajax

```
   $.ajax({
            url:'@Url.Action("BaixarConta","BaixarConta"),
            method:'post',
            data:{_Atributo_1:_Atributo_1 ,_Atributo_2:_Atributo_2,_Atributo_3:_Atributo_3}
            success:function(retorno){
                window.location='@Url.Action("Download","BaixarConta")?file='+retorno.FileGuid;
            }
    });
```

Action Download

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(string file)
{
     //faço o processamento do arquivo a ser baixado
     string handle=Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     var pdfStream= TempData[file];

     return  File(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Tiago S na `action Download` sempre retorna `null`, perdi algum tempinho tentando identificar o porque rs e não sei mais o que fazer rs editei a pergunta e adicionei mais detalhes, desde já agradeço a você ou qualquer outro que puder ajudar.

Comment: Você diz que esta chamada `window.location='@Url.Action("Download","BaixarConta")?file='+retorno.FileGuid` quando chega no controler e no método `Download` está chegando null o parametro file, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Tiaho S

Comment: Uma vez eu tive problema com isso, neste caso, você adiciona uma `/` antes do `?file` ficando assim `window.location='@Url.Action("Download","BaixarConta")/?file=‌​'+retorno.FileGuid`

Comment: Adicionando a barra funciona **sim**, mas tive que tirar o `new { {target='_blank'}` da `@Utl.Action` e agora estou com outro problema, pois a tela do sistema fecha ao invés de abrir uma nova aba do navegador para esse pdf.

Comment: No lugar do `windows.location` utilize `windows.open()` no seu caso fica assim: `window.open( '@Url.Action("Download","BaixarConta")/?file‌​=‌​'+retorno.FileGui‌​d,
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);`

Comment: Muito bom! Parabéns ! Obrigado @Tiago S, funcionou!